# Text off centre when using display inline-block

Tags: css, less

The logo text on my site is for some reason offcentre. I can make it centred again by turning off `display: inline-block`. However this flattens the spacing around the text and I'm unable to get spacing back above the text (can't do vertical padding for inline elements).
How am I able to centre the text with the background colour?  (trying to add `text-align: center` is automatically scored out in chrome dev tools for some reason?

[image: inline-block]
[image: no inline-block]

HTML

```
<h1 class="logo">
                <a href="/"><span class="text logo-title">SomeLogoText</span></a>
            </h1>
```

less (css)

```
h1.logo {
        font-family: "Roboto Slab", arial, sans-serif;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15px;
        float: left;

        a {
            color: #fff;
            padding: 15px 30px;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 1.4;
            max-width: 155px;
            background: @color;
            .border-radiuses(0, 4px, 4px, 0);
            .transition (color 0.4s ease-in-out);
            position: relative;
            font-size: 20px;

            &:hover {
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }
        .logo-title {
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: 1.6;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Inline elements* **ignore** `width`, and also `max-width`.

Your text simply doesn't fit the `max-width: 155px;` that you specify in your LESS code.

As soon as you take `display: inline-block;` *off* the element, it becomes `display: inline;` *per default* and thus **ignores** your `max-width: 155px;` and so the element becomes wider to contain the text.

If you have to stick to those `155px` all you can do is try to reduce the `padding-left` and `padding-right`, e.g. `padding: 15px 10px;` and see if your text fits then.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so well. That's a great help

Answer (score 0):

What you need is either:

- Increase the max-with on `.a` (current value 155px)
- Reduce the padding left/right on `.a` (current value 30px)
  until the text fit the background

Answer (score 0):

If a logo you could get away with giving the box a fixed width, as the text wont dynamically change, just match the box to logo width (or wider with centered text). If you need vertical spacing you could add an inline-block element inside the logo which contains the logo link itself